# How do I get my function R.loop to respond to the button click

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

The following code starts a motor with a button click. I have tried uncommenting the R.loop() however it takes over the whole GUI and displays the command prompt with the code running. The code runs fine it's just a matter of getting the code to respond to the button clicks.

```py
#begin GUI CODE

main = tk.Tk()
main.title('REGENERATOR')
main.geometry('800x800')    

#createing global variable for motor run
global is_on
is_on=False

#The following code is to run/stop the motor

def motor_run():
    global is_on
    running_setup = R.setup()
    #running_motor = R.loop()
            
def on_start():
    if is_on:
        Button_run.config()
        motor_run = True
    
    
def on_stop():
    if is_on:
        Button_stop.config()
        motor_run = False   
    

frame5 = LabelFrame(main_canvas, text="Run Program", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 20))
frame5.grid(row=3, column=0)

main_canvas.create_window((0,630), window=frame5, height=150, width= 200, anchor="s")

Button_run=Button(frame5, text="run", command=on_start, bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
Button_run.grid(row="2", column="0")

Button_stop=Button(frame5, text="stop", command=on_stop,  bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
Button_stop.grid(row="2", column="1")

# function calls
on_stop()
on_start()
motor_run()
update_value()
update_bat_1()
update_bat_2()
update_gen1()
main_canvas.mainloop()
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be in the placement of the Button_run.config(), It seems like you have the program asking itself for that command only if the motor is already on/off...you could try something like this...

```
def on_start():
    When Button_run.config() = True
        motor_run = True

def on_stop():
    When Button_stop.config()
        motor_run = False
```

Again, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it because I'm unfamiliar with coding in robotics but i think that may have something to do with it.

Comment: When I try this it says that Button_run.config()=True can't be assigned to the function call

Comment: Maybe try while instead of when...like i said idk what im doing so im not sure about any of this

Answer (score 0):

When you use this `import tkinter as tk`. Then add `tk.` to every widgets you added.

- You are missing `Canvas` widget.
- Comment out in line 50, `#main_canvas.mainloop()`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
main = tk.Tk()
main.title('REGENERATOR')
main.geometry('800x800')    

#createing global variable for motor run
global is_on
is_on=False

#The following code is to run/stop the motor

def motor_run():
    global is_on
    running_setup = R.setup()
    #running_motor = R.loop()
            
def on_start():
    if is_on:
        Button_run.config()
        motor_run = True
    
    
def on_stop():
    if is_on:
        Button_stop.config()
        motor_run = False   

canvas = tk.Canvas(main, width=600, height=400, bg='white')
canvas.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True)

frame5 = tk.LabelFrame(canvas, text="Run Program", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 20))
frame5.grid(row=3, column=0)

canvas.create_window((0,630), window=frame5, height=150, width= 200, anchor="s")

Button_run = tk.Button(frame5, text="run", command=on_start, bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
Button_run.grid(row="2", column="0")

Button_stop = tk.Button(frame5, text="stop", command=on_stop,  bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
Button_stop.grid(row="2", column="1")

# function calls
on_stop()
on_start()
motor_run()
update_value()
update_bat_1()
update_bat_2()
update_gen1()
#main_canvas.mainloop()
main.mainloop()
```

Screenshot. This is what it looks like using `Canvas`:

[image]